# Algorithm: Find smallest multiple

Tags: algorithm, math, time, complexity-theory

Let there be some positive integer Z and let there be a list of N, non-negative integers labeled z0 ... zn-1 What is an algorithm that can find the smallest multiple of Z that can be expressed in terms of the sum of all zi * ci where ci is any nonnegative integer constant?

This algorithm needs to run in time O(Z * ( N + log(Z) )).

I tried to solve this using djikstras algorithm and got as far as estblishing that there would have to be Z * N edges and Z vertices in order to fulfill the time complexity requirement. I also figured out that each ni can have at most Z different coefficients since (min zi)/zi * Z is bound by Z.

Perhaps there is some way to do this by exploring a cyclic graph setup?

Comment: What are the ni?  The problem statement only mentions Z, N, zi and ci.

Comment: Also I presume your zi start at i=1, not i=0, otherwise there are N+1 of them.

Comment: And that your ci are restricted to integers, since otherwise the problem is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

You should lookup the [Frobenius problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) (or Chicken McNugget problem).

Given two relatively prime integers `(a,b)`, all numbers `>= (a-1)(b-1) + 1` can be written as `xa + yb` for non-negative integers `x,y`.

Using this, your search space is drastically reduced.